# PHP get downloads from page but not page itself

Tags: php, pdf, fetch

I have a page. When it's opened it triggers PDF-file dowloading. Is it possible with PHP to get that file (not the page itself).

Comment: Hi, I think we need a bit more explanation, a view of the code would also be helpful. PS Neat handle, fitting for the lack of information :)

Comment: when this page opens it makes AJAX request to server that return pdf file. and this pdf downloads to compiter

Comment: Its still not clear what you mean by _Is it possible with PHP to get that file_ As I assume it is a php script that is getting that file from disk and sending it back to the AJAX call

Comment: I don't have access to that page's server. I need save that file in a folder on MY server to manipulate with it further

Comment: So what's the problem exactly? What have you researched and tried so far? In principle it's simple - get php to make a HTTP request to the same URL which the AJAX call is requesting (ensuring you set the same headers, parameters, request body content, if any). You can use cURL or Guzzle, or even file_get_contents for that.

Comment: @ADyson I can't do AJAX bacause the URL is uniqe and containts tokens, keys, etc..

Comment: Obviously the remote server may have some restrictions which make it difficult or impossible to replicate the functionality, but we don't know since we know nothing about the site you're trying to access. You just need to try it out. You could also do a test run using a tool such as Postman to build the request, to ensure it's generally possible. Postman can even then generate PHP code for you automatically, to replicate the same HTTP request.

Comment: @GyuMaupassant I didn't say to do AJAX, I said to do a HTTP request. AJAX is a browser-based technology which can generate HTTP requests. PHP can make a regular HTTP request though. If the request generated by the website contains tokens etc then you need to replicate them in your Postman- or PHP-based request. If the URL is somehow randomly generated or you require authentication tokens which are issued by the site's login process, then you're probably not going to be able to achieve it easily, not without a lot of extra work, or trying to use a headless browser to simulate, or something

Comment: Probably, the site is created like that to stop you automating the downloading of the content without permission, or hotlinking to it, or anything else the owners of the content might consider undesirable. Is this restricted content? Licensed? Paywalled?

Comment: @ADyson no, nothing like that. Just an ordinary PDF. I am thinking of simulating that page dowloading with PHP script which will be located on my server. when this script runs it simulates that page opening and file downloads to my server folder. that's how I see it now.